# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '[] | iCommits'.ts(7053)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm having a fair amount of issues with this file migration to typescript, so overall would appreciate any feedback on what could be improved to make this more type safe and less redundant possibly. This is the code block I am working with:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

interface iProps {
  repoName: string
}

interface iCommits {
  [index: string]: iCommit[],

}

interface iCommit {
  sha: string,
  commit: iCommitData
}

interface iCommitData {
  author: iAuthor
  message: string
}

interface iAuthor {
  name: string,
  email: string,
  date: number
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
const CommitList = (props: iProps) => {
  const repoName = props.repoName
  const [commitList, setCommitList] = useState<iCommits | []>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/repos/mathiusjohnson/${repoName}/commits`)
      .then(res => {
        setCommitList(res.data)
      })
  }, [repoName])

  const commitKeys = Object.keys(commitList)
  
  console.log(commitList[commitKeys[0] as keyof iCommits]);

  const renderedCommits = commitKeys !== undefined && commitKeys.length > 0
    ? (commitKeys as string[]).map((commit: string, index: number) => {

        if (index !== 0) {
          return null
        } else {
          const startTimeISOString = commitList[commit as keyof iCommits].commit.author.date
          const startTimeDate = new Date(startTimeISOString).toDateString()
          console.log("latest commit: ", startTimeDate);


          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <p>Author: {commitList[commit].commit.author.name}</p>
              <p>Committed on: {startTimeDate}</p>
              <p>Commit message: {sortedCommits[commit].commit.message}</p>
            </li>
          )
        }
      })
    : ''

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Most recent commit</h2>
      <ol>{renderedCommits}</ol>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CommitList
```

You can test the axios call out if you need to with this url (not related to this current project, just the first one I thought of to share that is not private):

```
https://api.github.com/repos/mathiusjohnson/social_network_api/commits
```

My issue right now I'm getting is this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type '[] | iCommits'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '[] | iCommits'.ts(7053)
```

On any code that I'm trying to use a key in the commitList in code block below, like this console.log:

```
  console.log(commitList[commitKeys[0] as keyof iCommits]);
```

Again, any overall feedback for improvement is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some logic which is not required in your sample file.

Additionally you expected commitList to be ICommits which is a object - that is incorrect.

commitList is a array of ICommit(based on this api call https://api.github.com/repos/mathiusjohnson/social_network_api/commits).

Interface names start with a Uppercase I so I changed e.g iCommit to ICommit.

A functional example of your code can be found https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-heisenberg-ejmgk?file=/src/types.ts

I left some of your code intentionally so that you can see what changes I did and commented above it that it can be deleted(once you delete that code there are no more errors/warnings in this sample project).

tldr: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-heisenberg-ejmgk?file=/src/types.ts

Comment: Awesome!! Looks great, thanks for putting so much time into it. And yes, my intention is to get the latest commit :)